# How to put xml site map in asp.net mvc application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, xml-sitemap

I created a xml site map file manually for my asp.net mvc 4 application.
Now how can i use this file for SEO improvement? what should i do with this file?
thank you

Comment: At a minimum you'll want to inform robots of the location of your sitemap: `Sitemap: http://www.example.com/sitemap.xml`. Other than that you may want to sign up for Google Webmasters and whatever the Bing equivalent is to inform them of the sitemap if they aren't already indexing your website.

Comment: for creating this url "http://www.example.com/sitemap.xml" , do i need to create a action result or just copy this file to root folder of my application?

Comment: Just copy it to your root (or any other location). Update the `robots.txt` file with the url. See http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html

Comment: thanks mate, it hepled alot